# Problem executing PL/SQL code using stored procedures

Tags: plsql

I think code is correct but compiler throws this exception:

Error(6,1): PLS-00201: el identificador 'DKMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE' se debe declarar

This is code I´m trying to run:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SET VERIFY OFF;

BEGIN
  p_sumar(5,4);
  p_sumar(8,9);
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_sumar (numero1 NUMBER, numero2 NUMBER)
IS
resultado NUMBER;
BEGIN
resultado:=numero1+numero2;
DKMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('La suma es: ' ||resultado);
END p_sumar;
/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PLS-00201 - identifier must be declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526870/pls-00201-identifier-must-be-declared)

Comment: Should it be ```DBMS_OUTPUT``` instead of ```DKMS_OUTPUT```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved problem by myself, there was an spell mistake in DKMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(..)
it´s dbms:output....